# Heroku 404 error / no global web.xml found

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, heroku

I've created a very simple query in java (jdbc/JAX-RS). The code will ultimately act as a web service layer for an android app. The query works if I create and query a local dummy database (running it as a java app in eclipse) but if I run it on a local Tomcat server I get a 404 error. Similarly, when I redirect the query to an external database on heroku, deploy the app and database, etc I get 404 errors from heroku as well.

My heroku log doesn't explicitly give me any errors but perhaps these are to blame? Any other ideas if not?

```
2015-10-19T03:05:44.293588+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: No global web.xml found
2015-10-19T03:05:50.795221+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

FYI to the extent that it's helpful, I deploy my code from Eclipse EE with a maven build (Goals: heroku:deploy-war).

Thanks again!

Comment: The messages you posted are not errors. They are expected. Are you running the app locally with `heroku local`? or with webapp-runner? Try that (because that's what heroku does). What routes are you trying to hit but getting 404?

Comment: I'm deploying my app to heroku from eclipse by running a maven build, following these instruction: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea. I then go to the heroku site on my browser and click open app. I'll try the webapp-runner route as well. thanks

Comment: Try using `mvn heroku:run-war` to test locally.

Comment: when i run that or run mvn package and then java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war   the command line gets to this line, INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]     , but never actually starts it (i waited for over 20 minutes on one of the runs). Will try and look into this to see if anyone else has encountered the same error tomorrow night

Comment: ya ,I have the same issue while running the war .it got stuck at 80% in tomcatRunWar.anything to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be in URL. For local server the URL should be `localhost:8080/page` instead of `localhost:8080/name_of_app/page`.

Answer (score 0):

I've created TWO **java+maven+tomcat+heroku projects**.
And ran into your exact problem. I just created
a 3RD deployment to replicate the problem again
to make sure my advice is correct.

The "No global web.xml found" is a "red herring / distraction" from real problem.
If your web.xml is in:

```
<HEROKU_MAVEN_TOMCAT_FOLDER>\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
```

And is correct, then ignore that message.
Use "heroku logs --tail" and search for
"**Error R10**".

## 1: Fixing Problem From This Message:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed 
>   to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

Likely this is because you are using your 
LOCALHOST commands in your procfile instead 
of the PRODUCTION/LIVE commands.

Example:

**CORRECT:** (contents of procfile (all lowercase, no extension))

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

**WRONG:** (contents of procfile (all lowercase, no extension))

```
web: java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 5001 target/*.war
```

While

> java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 5001 target/*.war

Is **correct** when deploying to **localhost**, 
its the **wrong** command for your **procfile**.

## 2: Your Next Problem:

When I say "next problem"
I mean the next error you are likely to
end up with after fixing the previous problem.

> The origin server did not find a current 
>   representation for the target resource 
>   or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Problem #2 Fix:
For the root of the site to respond, it needs
either:
1. A servlet that maps to url pattern "/"
2. An index.html in src/main/webapp
I used the quickest fix and made this
index.jsp file:

```
<html><body>
<h2>HELLO_FROM_SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP_INDEX_JSP</h2>
</body></html>
```